# Three.js: Why the shadow doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I keep studing Three.js. I charge a 3D model with the function JSONLoader and when I want to put it a shadow, it doesn't appear and I don't know why because I think I do all the steps:

1- Active the the ShadowMap.

2- I have lights.

3- The plane has recieveShadow = true;

4- The 3D model has castShadow = true;

The completily code (**now it's working**):

```
<html><head>
<title>Ejemplo 9 Three.js</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->

<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/dat.gui.js/dat.gui.js"></script>

<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/threex.windowresize-master/threex.windowresize.js"></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/threex.keyboardstate-master/threex.keyboardstate.js"></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/orbitcontrols/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "plugins/ColladaLoader/ColladaLoader.js"></script>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.css">

<style>
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #renderer{
        overflow: hidden

    }

    .container-fluid{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .col-md-12{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul>
                <li>Up, Down, Left, Right-> Move cube. </li>
                <li>Z & X -> Rotate cube. </li>
                <li>WASD -> Scale cube.</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="renderer">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var renderer;

            var controls;

            var scene;
            var keyboard;


            var material;
            var plane_texture;
            var grass;

            var geometry_cube;
            var cube_material;
            var cube_texture;
            var cube;

            //Modelo 3D .js
            var model3D;
            var materials_modelo3D; //materiales
            var final_model; //vértices + materiales

            //Modelo 3D .dae
            var model3Ddae;
            var final_modeldae;

            var speed;
            var space;
            var time;

            var width;
            var height;
            var fov;
            var aspect;
            var near;
            var far;

            var camera;


            var light;
            var ambient_light;
            var solar_light;

            start();

            function start(){

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled= true;
                width = window.innerWidth-10;
                height = window.innerHeight-10;
                //alert("ancho: " + width + ", alto:" + height);
                renderer.setSize(width, height);
                $("#renderer").append(renderer.domElement);

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();

                model3D = new THREE.JSONLoader(); //vertices
                model3Ddae = new THREE.ColladaLoader();



                fov = 45; //angle
                aspect = width/height;
                near = 0.1;
                far = 1000;

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (fov, aspect, near, far);

                THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);

                var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(250, 250, 250)");
                renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(color));

                camera.position.z= 20;
                camera.position.y= 10;
                scene.add(camera);

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

                plane_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("texturas/cesped.jpg");

                cube_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("texturas/muro.jpg");

                crear_plano();
                model3D.load("models/layers260a.js", functionAddModel);
    //          model3Ddae.load("models/rifle.dae" , functionAddModelDae);

    //          cube();
                makeLight();

                var ejesAyuda = new THREE.AxesHelper(20); //son los ejes de ayuda creo
                scene.add(ejesAyuda); 

                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            }

            function crear_plano(){
                geometria_plano = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 10, 10);

                plane_texture.wrapS = plane_texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // para repetir la textura a lo largo y a lo width
                plane_texture.repeat.set(10, 10); // tablero de 10 x 10

                //material y agregado de textura
                material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: plane_texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
                grass = new THREE.Mesh(geometria_plano, material);

                //grass.rotation.y=-0.5;
                grass.rotation.x=Math.PI/2;

                grass.receiveShadow=true;

                scene.add(grass);
            }

            function functionAddModel(geometry){
                    imagen = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("models/mario.jpg");
                    materials_modelo3D = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: imagen});

                    final_model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials_modelo3D);
                    scene.add(final_model);

                    final_model.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
                    final_model.position.set(10, 13, 10);
                    final_model.rotation.y = Math.PI;

                    final_model.castShadow = true;
                    final_model.receiveShadow = false;

                    animation();
            }

            function functionAddModelDae(infodae){
                final_modeldae = infodae.scene;
                final_modeldae.position.set(20, 5, 10);
                final_modeldae.scale.x = final_modeldae.scale.y = final_modeldae.scale.z =.2;
            //  final_modeldae.rotation.y = Math.PI;

                scene.add(final_modeldae);

            }

            function animation(){
                requestAnimationFrame(animation);
                render_modelo();

                var objMov = final_model;

                speed = 100; 
                time = 0.001;

                space = speed * time;

                if(keyboard.pressed("up")){ //tecla flecha arriba
                    objMov.position.z+=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("down")){
                    objMov.position.z-=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("right")){
                    objMov.position.x+=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("left")){
                    objMov.position.x-=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("z")){
                    objMov.rotation.x+=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("x")){
                    objMov.rotation.y+=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("w")){
                    objMov.scale.y+=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("a")){
                    objMov.scale.x-=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("s")){
                    objMov.scale.y-=space;
                }else if(keyboard.pressed("d")){
                    objMov.scale.x+=space;
                }
                controls.target.set(objMov.position.x, objMov.position.y, objMov.position.z);
            }

            function render_modelo(){
                controls.update();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }   

            function cube(){
                geometry_cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 10, 10);
                cube_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:cube_texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false});
                cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_cube, cube_material);
                cube.position.x= -4;
                cube.position.y = 6;
                cube.position.z = 0;

                cube.castShadow = true;
                scene.add(cube);

            }

            function makeLight(){
                light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
                light.position.set(-100,200,100);
                scene.add(light);
                ambient_light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000);
                scene.add(ambient_light);

                solar_light = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
                solar_light.position.set(500, 500, -500);
                solar_light.castShadow = true;
                solar_light.intensity = 1.3;



                solar_light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
                solar_light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
                solar_light.shadow.camera.near = 250;
                solar_light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;

                intensidad=50;

                solar_light.shadowCameraLeft = -intensidad;
                solar_light.shadowCameraRight = intensidad;
                solar_light.shadowCameraTop = intensidad;
                solar_light.shadowCameraBottom = -intensidad;

                scene.add(solar_light);


                var helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera );
                var helper2 = new THREE.CameraHelper(solar_light.shadow.camera);

                scene.add(helper);
                scene.add(helper2);
            }

        });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The scene:
[image]

Thanks for you help, as always :)

Comment: Because we don't have your model files, would you please post an image of what your current render looks like? Also, I see you have already done some debugging with camera helpers. What was the result of that debugging? Did everything appear to be correct?

Comment: what is the size of your model? it seems to be close to 100. Yet your camera far plane is at 10000 and your shadow camera far is it 20000. Increasing these values actually loses you resolution. They should be as tight as your scene size is.

Comment: I am watching tutorial, for this reason, I have this values. I changed the light's function for only have one light (directional light), i changed the position values too and I removed some code lines that I think it doesn't neccesary. The shadow doesn't appear yet. I going to upload a image of scene. Thanks.

Comment: This line (`solar_light.shadow.camera.far = 30;`) may be too shallow. Give it a (much) larger value, like `1000`, and try again. If that doesn't work, try swapping your `DirectionalLight` for a `PointLight` to see if you get _any_ shadows.

Comment: Ok, now it's working! But I modified "solar light" position too for that it's farther (500, 500, -500) because the shadow only was shown in a little piece of map. I'm so glad for the help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your "grass" material is a `MeshBasicMaterial`. As the name implies, it is purely basic, and does not respond to light sources.

Interestingly, `MeshBsicMaterial` can *cast* shadows,
 but cannot receive them.
 (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8116#issuecomment-183459078).

Change your grass material to `MeshLambertMaterial`, and the shadows will appear.

Comment: OMG! thank you, I spent hours searching some error and...I knew it was some silly thing...thanks!!

Comment: Sorry but I though it was the solution but I changed MeshBasicMaterial for MeshLambertMaterial and the shadow still doesn't appear.

Comment: try to add an ambientLight 
`scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666));`